# Join two lists into one dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

These are my lists (both lists have the same length - 43 indices):

```
list1 = [u'UMTS', u'UMTS', u'UMTS', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'GSM', u'LTE']

list2 = [u'60000', u'60000', u'60000', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'120000', u'120000', u'120000', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'120000', u'120000', u'120000', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'300000']
```

I would like to join them into one dictionary:

```
dictionary = {
    'UMTS' : 'indices from 0 to 2'
    'GSM' : 'indices from 3 to 42'
    'LTE' : 'index 43'
}
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Is it possible at all? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I should add that in other cases lists may have more or less indices (but always the same amount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict()` and `zip()` function:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
...     d[i].append(j)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'UMTS': [u'60000', u'60000', u'60000'], u'GSM': [u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'120000', u'120000', u'120000', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'120000', u'120000', u'120000', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629'], u'LTE': [u'300000']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like this.

```
result = {}
for i in set(list1):
     result.update({i:[]})
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
     result[i].append(j)
```

**Result**

```
{u'UMTS': [u'60000', u'60000', u'60000'], u'GSM': [u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'120000', u'120000', u'120000', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'120000', u'120000', u'120000', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629'], u'LTE': [u'300000']}
```

**Concept**

Created a dictionary with the possible values in the `list1` and an empty list as value. With using `set` you will get the elements only once. And iterate through the `list1` and `list2` and insert values directly to the list corresponding.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with a single for loop. Isn't this what you want?

```
>>> for i in range(0,len(list1)):
...     if(mydict.get(list1[i]) is None):
...             mydict[list1[i]]=[list2[i]]
...     else:
...             mydict[list1[i]].append(list2[i])
...
>>> mydict
{u'UMTS': [u'60000', u'60000', u'60000'], u'GSM': [u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'120000', u'120000', u'120000', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'120512', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'120000', u'120000', u'120000', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629', u'118629'], u'LTE': [u'300000']}
```

Comment: How you got an extra `60000` in result ?

Comment: @RahulKP Thank you for pointing out... mydict has some content that was appended...now cleared it and again ran... now it looks fine...